# Lasso regression with GAM models in R

Tags: r, regression, lasso, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm using a regression package that uses `gam()` from the `mgcv` package. Is it possible to include an L1 penalty with the `gam` function? The documentation indicates that an L2 penalty can be used using the *H* parameter, but I do not understand how, or if it can be used for the lasso as well. Splines are not in the model; the only reason why I'm not using `glmnet` is because the function I use has GAM implemented. Example code:

```
formula.eq = Y ~ X
model.out = gam(formula.eq, binomial(link = "logit"), gamma = 1)
```

Where `Y` is a vector of zeros and ones, and `X` includes > 400 features, so I need to perform some shrinkage method.
Thanks.

Comment: Say again, why don't you use `glmnet`?

Comment: If you do not want a splines in your model why even use mgcv::gam??. What function are you using?